# Why is My Flash AS2 form emailing more than the requested fields

Tags: php, forms, flash, email

This code is for a flash builder that picks colors and styles for uniforms. I am just adding this .swf into a site and I need it to send the results to the sites email. I added one line of code into the script so it can "Post" the result to the php handler included with Godaddy Hosting and it is sending the emails correctly But in the emails I am getting more than just the results. I am seeing information about the website it is on as well as the array of options not selected. here is the code (line 26 is where I added the post command):

```
stop();
//
function formcheck() {
    _root.youthRequest = check1.checked;
    _root.adultRequest = check2.checked;
    if (_root.theNamefirst == "" or _root.theNamelast == "" or _root.theEmail == "" or _root.thePhone == "" or _root.theState == "") {
    status_txt.text = "Input Required";
} else {
    _root.colorSortFn();
    if (_root.font_style != "block" && _root.font_style != "omega" && text2style == "shadow") {
        //temporary holders, to be reset later
        tmpVar = _root.text2style;
        tmpVar2 = _root.text2_colorVar;
        _root.text2style = "NA";
        _root.text2_colorVar = "";
    }
    sortColorTypeFn("insert");
    sortColorTypeFn("insert2");
    sortColorTypeFn("piping");
    sortColorTypeFn("piping2");
    sortColorTypePantsFn("insert1");
    sortColorTypePantsFn("insert2");
    sortColorTypePantsFn("piping");
    // send call
    _root.loadVariables("/submit-gear-builder.aspx", "POST");
    _root.loadVariables("/mailer.php", "POST");
    // reset variables
    if (_root.font_style != "block" && _root.font_style != "omega" && text2style == "shadow") {
        _root.text2style = tmpVar;
        _root.text2_colorVar = tmpVar2;
    }
    _root.colorSortFn();
    play();
}
}
//
_root.theNamefirst;
_root.theNamelast;
_root.theEmail;
_root.thePhone;
_root.theSchool;
_root.theState;
_root.youthRequest;
_root.adultRequest;
_root.theComments;
// 
function clearform() {
_root.theNamefirst = "";
_root.theNamelast = "";
_root.theEmail = "";
_root.thePhone = "";
_root.theSchool = "";
_root.theState = "";
_root.youthRequest = "";
_root.adultRequest = "";
_root.theComments = "";
check1.gotoAndStop(1);
check2.gotoAndStop(1);
status_txt.text = "";
//                                                                                       
// 
}
clearform();
send_btn.enabled = true;
// set tab order
button_btn.tabEnabled = true;
exit_btn.tabEnabled = true;
//
theNamefirst.tabIndex = 1;
theNamelast.tabIndex = 2;
theEmail.tabIndex = 3;
thePhone.tabIndex = 4;
theSchool.tabIndex = 5;
theState.tabIndex = 6;
check1.tabIndex = 7;
check2.tabIndex = 8;
theComments.tabIndex = 9;
button_btn.tabIndex = 10;
exit_btn.tabIndex = 11;
```